# Combining files and adding filename within combined file(or timestamp within filename)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script which loops through a series of json files in a directory and combines them. It also adds a square bracket at the beginning and end of the combined file, and a comma between each file combined(to form a Json array).

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
dir /b /s /a-d C:\JSON_LOADER\Pre_Processing_Files\JSON_FILE*.json >files.temp
call :read <files.temp
del files.temp
del /q C:\JSON_LOADER\Pre_Processing_Files\JSON_FILE*.json
exit /b

:read
set "file="
set /p "file="
if not defined file exit /b
for /f "delims=/ tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%DATE:~4%") do (
    for /f "delims=:. tokens=1-4" %%m in ("%TIME: =0%") do (
        set /a cnt=%%c-%%b-%%a-%%m%%n%%o%%p
    )
)
call :write >C:\JSON_LOADER\COMBINED\JSON_FILE-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%-%cnt%.json
goto :read

:write
echo [
type "!file!"
echo(
for /l %%N in (2 1 10000) do (
 set "file="
 set /p "file="
 if not defined file goto :end
 echo ,
 type "!file!"
 echo(
)
:end
echo ]
exit /b
```

What I would like to do is also add the file name of each file at the end of each record in the combined file. The filename contains a timestamp that I require when loading the data into SQL. a sample filename would be;

```
JSON_FILE-20160816-104507.json
```

Ideally I would like the capture the '20160816-104507' timestamp section only, however I would be happy with just the full filename also, as I can process this filename in SQL. For the example above, I would like to add;

```
,"Filename":"JSON_FILE-20160816-104507.json"
```

A further complication is that each .json file that I am combining is contained within curly braces `{}` . I would require the filename that I am inserting to appear before the last curly brace } of each line. So for example, a sample of the current resulting combined file is;

```
[
{"object":"JSON_FILE","eventType":"CREATE","JsonId":12345}
,
{"object":"JSON_FILE","eventType":"CREATE","JsonId":123445}
,
{"object":"JSON_FILE","eventType":"CREATE","JsonId":123455}
]
```

I would like to append the filename information(or timestamp within the filename) to the end of each record, but within the curly brace like this example;

```
[
{"object":"JSON_FILE","eventType":"CREATE","JsonId":12345,"Filename":"JSON_FILE-20160816-104507.json"}
,
{"object":"JSON_FILE","eventType":"CREATE","JsonId":12345,"Filename":"JSON_FILE-20160816-104601.json"}
,
{"object":"JSON_FILE","eventType":"CREATE","JsonId":12345,"Filename":"JSON_FILE-20160816-104929.json"}
]
```

Another option, if it is a possibility, is to run the files before combining though F.A.R.T, replacing the final curly bracket with `,"Filename":"[filename]"}` however I'm unsure of how to capture the file name in a recursive find and replace in the application.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too!

Comment: Each JSON file contains only a line like _{"object":"JSON_FILE","eventType":"CREATE","JsonId":123445}_ ?

Comment: Yes. Each file is a single line json, contained with curly braces. There are a few more fields, however I've simplified it slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
setlocal
  :: Set options
  set SourceFileFilter=JSON_FILE*.json
  set resultFile=result.txt

  ::Process each file
  echo [ > %resultFile%
  set IsFirst=1
  for %%i in (%SourceFileFilter%) do call :ProcessFile "%%i"
  echo ] >> %resultFile%

endlocal & goto:eof



:ProcessFile
setlocal
  :: THE FOLLOWING LINES ARE OPTIONAL, JUST TO GET TIMESTAMP (STORED IN LOCAL VARIABLE)
    set Timestamp=%~1
    set Timestamp=%Timestamp:JSON_FILE-=%
    set Timestamp=%Timestamp:.json=%
    echo The timestamp is stored in the local %%Timestamp%% variable: %Timestamp%
  :: END OPTIONAL

  :: Add "," if not the first processed file
  if NOT "%IsFirst%"=="1" echo ,>> %resultFile% 
  set /p JsonFile=<%1
  :: %JsonFile:}=% removes the } char
   echo %JsonFile:}=%,"Filename":"%~1"}>> %resultFile%

 :: End local environment, but before ending it, save IsFirst (as empty) for external usage, then exit
endlocal & set "IsFirst=" & goto:eof
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of continuous lines containing only commas, which is breaking the array aspect of the combined file. Is it possible to edit the original script at the beginning of the question to write the file name, as you have don in this script?

Comment: just copy the parts into your code. i commented everything to make things easy for you.